# knockout.js observable array binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is my code

```
<div data-bind="foreach: baselist">
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: basename"></span>
    <div data-bind="foreach: subItems">
       <span data-bind="text: subitemname"></span>
         <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removecard">Del</a>
    </div>     
</div>
 <button data-bind="click:addChild">Add</button>
```

this is my viewmodel

```
    var SimpleListModel2 = function(baselist) {

     this.baselist= ko.observableArray(baselist);
     this.addChild = function(list) {
       alert(list.basename());
    }.bind(this);

    self.removecard = function (cardlist) {
                this.cardlists.remove(cardlist);
     };
};
```

this is my data i am passing to the viewmodel. How can i include baselist in this data? It cant find baselist

```
var initialData = [{
    { basename: "Danny", subItems: [
        { subitemname: "Mobile"},
        { subitemname: "Home"}]
    },
    { basename: "Sensei", subItems: [
        { subitemname: "Mobile"},
        { subitemname: "Home"}]
    }];
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: how can i include baselist inside the initialData?

Comment: So that it can be passed to the viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the html that you provided, I can see that the structure is like this.

baselist -> {(baseName), (subItems -> subitemName)}

So it seems like you just need to pass the data to viewModel during initialization. And remove parenthesis `alert(list.basename);` here because this is not an observable object.

```js
var SimpleListModel2 = function(baselist) {
  this.baselist = ko.observableArray(baselist);
  this.addChild = function(list) {
    alert(list.basename);
  }.bind(this);
};

var initialData = [
{ basename: "Danny", subItems: [
  { subitemname: "Mobile"},
  { subitemname: "Home"}]
},
{ basename: "Sensei", subItems: [
  { subitemname: "Mobile"},
  { subitemname: "Home"}]
}]; 

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel2(initialData));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: baselist">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: basename"></span>
    <div data-bind="foreach: subItems">
      <span data-bind="text: subitemname"></span>
    </div>     
  </div>
  <button data-bind="click:$parent.addChild">Add</button>
</div>
```